# Set number format to General

Tags: excel, office-js

I want to set a specific value in a table to default format "General".
To implement this I follow the spec:
[Blank and null values in Excel add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-blank-null-values)

> When you specify a blank value for a property (i.e., two quotation
> marks with no space in-between ''), it will be interpreted as an
> instruction to clear or reset the property. For example:
>
> ...
> If you specify a blank value for the
> numberFormat property, the number format is reset to General.
> ...

My code is:

```
const formats = [["0", "0"], ["", "0.00"], ["0.00", "0.00"]];    
const range = sheet.getRange("D3:E5");
range.numberFormat = formats;
```

The usage of empty quote lead to an error message from the excel.js API :

**message: "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."**

Comment: Try using single quotation marks instead of double. If that doesn't fix it, please reproduce this in the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862) tool and export a gist. Then provide a link to the gist. Thanks.

Comment: Using single quotation lead to the same result "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.". I create a gist and the link is: https://gist.github.com/Nassim33/b16d125daa0c58d503820346847978d5 @RickKirkham

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly for me. There's no error and the cell is set to General format. I'm working on Excel for Windows. What platform are you working on? Mac? Online? Windows?

Comment: I'm working on Excel desktop version on Windows. My version of Excel is : "Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.01.13231.20110) 32-bit" @RickKirkham

Comment: Maybe that's a bad build. I'm on 16.01,13401.20000 64 bit. Is there another Windows machine nearby that you could try it on to see if it's machine-relative?

Comment: I have update my Excel version 16.01.13328.20130 and now it's working. @RickKirkham